# Preventing adding duplicates to Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So here's the action that i'm testing out in my controller

```
def add_to_cart
    @cart = current_cart
    if @cart.tutors.where(params[:tutor_id]).empty?
      @cart.add_tutor(params[:tutor_id])
      flash[:success] = 'You have successfully added the tutor to your shortlist!'
      redirect_to show_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'You have already shortlisted the tutor!'
      redirect_to show_path
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about testing if `tutor_id` is present in the cart. I actually tried testing various methods of checking for the children's properties in rails console. I arrived at `Parent.Child.where(:id => X)` as a way to check if any of the children has id = X.

This is what shows up in my server (or development log) when the method is called.

```
Started POST "/add_to_cart/11" for 116.87.14.150 at 2016-10-16 07:32:09 +0000
Cannot render console from 116.87.14.150! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by CartsController#add_to_cart as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XzHaIJMzIz9I84W5tmLuj+28SBvVP9pc1JdZOyQaYEr286JNIw4J8tKtSON7eIWsdf0Lc6ogCdT2LrdtVVxGoA==", "tutor_id"=>"11"}
cart_id = 17
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tutors" INNER JOIN "cart_tutors" ON "tutors"."id" = "cart_tutors"."tutor_id" WHERE "cart_tutors"."cart_id" = ? AND (11)  [["cart_id", 17]]
```

Anyway it constantly processes the `else` portion which means its not working like i meant it to be, which probably means that its not checking for the ID like i intend for it to do. Am i using the correct method? If not, how should i be doing it insteaD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got some mistake in:

```
@cart.tutors.where(params[:tutor_id]).empty?
```

It makes not correct sql query:

```
WHERE "cart_tutors"."cart_id" = ? AND (11)
```

See **AND (11)**

Try next:

```
@cart.tutors.where(id: params[:tutor_id]).empty?
```

Comment: Hi it works perfectly. Thank you. Can i just clarify for understanding purposes, i know in rails4 doing `id:` is the same as doing `:id =>` so does that mean i should have done `.where(:id => params[:tutor_id])` like i did when testing out the query in my rails console?

Comment: `:id =>` - it's old syntax for hash. From ruby 1.9 recommended use `id: ` - but in general it's same.